# Creating a generic list of a generic type

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I am trying to create a list of a generic type in vb.net 2.0 framework.
This is the generic type definition:

```
----------
  Public Class GenericParamMap(Of T)

    Public Sub New(ByVal pParamName As String, ByVal pPropValue As T)
      mParamName = pParamName
      mPropValue = pPropValue
    End Sub

    Public Property ParamName() As String
      Get
        Return mParamName
      End Get
      Set(ByVal Value As String)
        mParamName = Value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private mParamName As String

    Public Property PropValue() As T
      Get
        Return mPropValue
      End Get
      Set(ByVal Value As T)
        mPropValue = Value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private mPropValue As T
  End Class
----------
```

And here is a method that would use a list of GenericParamMap passed in as a parameter:

```
Public Sub PopulateParamMap(ByVal pMap As List(Of GenericParamMap(Of T))
      pMap.Add(New GenericParamMap(Of Integer)("@region_id", RegionId))
      pMap.Add(New GenericParamMap(Of String)("@bus_addr1", BusAddress1))
      pMap.add(New GenericParamMap(Of Boolean)("@active_flag", ActiveFlag))
End Sub
----------
```

The compiler does not allow a "T" in the method's parameter because it's not defined, but I'm not sure how or where to define it. I thought it was okay to have a generic method definition. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: As a side node: I'm not sure if `GenericParamMap` is the right name for this. A *map* usually maps keys to values, so your `List(Of ...)` could be called a *map*, not the individual entries. What you describe as `GenericParamMap` is just a *tuple*, so you might call it `GenericTuple` or `GenericParamMapEntry`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn’t work because different instances of `GenericParamMap` don’t share a common base (except `Object`). That is, a `Thing(Of Integer)` is entirely unrelated to a `Thing(Of String)` as far as VB is concerned.

One way to solve this is to have your class implement an interface (or extend a base class) and then declare your list as `List(Of ThatInterface)`. Note that you will *lose* the generic type information that way, but there is fundamentally no way around this – you simply can’t integers and strings alike (except as far as their common base class goes, which is `Object`), and thus you also cannot treat `Thing(Of Integer)` and `Thing(Of String)` alike.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use generic method like below:

```
Public Sub PopulateParamMap(Of T)(ByVal pMap As List(Of GenericParamMap(Of T))
   pMap.Add(New GenericParamMap(Of T)("@region_id", RegionId))
End Sub
```

but you can't use your method for different types at the same time such as string, Integer...